# Copyright laws with personal pictures

Tags: copyright

If I put a presentation together and want to add my personal pictures from an office party does that violate any copyright laws?

Comment: By "my personal pictures", do you mean "pictures which I took"?

Comment: yes that's what I meant pictures I took

Answer (score 1):

It depends who owns the copyright. If the pictures were taken in the course of your duties as an employee (and pictures you take at an office party may be) then the copyright belongs to your employer and you need their permission. If not, they are your copyright and you can do what you like.

However, other laws apply. If you are using these pictures in a commercial way you will need a model release from each person who is the subject of the photograph (i.e. where they are a primary focus of the image, not where they are merely incidental). Using them in a portfolio to promote you in the job market is probably commercial.

Further, did you have permission of the controller of the premises to take photos in the first place?